# Update a field after running standard approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, lookup-column

I copied the approval workflow available. After completing the approval, I want one field related with the item that was approved to be updated.

I tried different ways but nothing works.

Should I include this action inside the approval step or in a separate step?

My last step is the following:

Update item in current item
List: current item

Set the field: Title
To this value: Invoice Peru: Approval Status Yes

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have that process run on its own workflow. Create a workflow that will look for when the first is Complete, you should have a column in the corresponding library of the workflow that gives you the workflow state for that Item. Use that column as a trigger for the new workflow and then use "set field in current item" to complete the process.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you include that step in approval workflow itself.

You can use sharepoint designer to add this step to your workflow.